# 500.19 - Internal Server Error on production server.

Tags: asp.net, webforms, web-config, iis-7.5, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have 500.19 - Internal Server Error on production server.

On the page I am trying to access I have a htmleditorextender from the ajaxcontroltoolkit. In order to make the htmleditorextender work on the development server I had to add the following entry to the web.config file:

```
<system.webServer>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
<handlers>
  <add name="AjaxFileUploadHandler" verb="*" path="AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd" type="AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadHandler, AjaxControlToolkit" />
</handlers>
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4294967295"/>
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
</system.webServer>
```

it all worked fine until I uploaded it to the production server (if it helps at all it is held in a 1 and 1 server.)
The error occurs at the following line:

```
      <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4294967295"/>
  </requestFiltering>
```

I cant remove the line because I need it for the htmleditorextender to work.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

config error:

```
This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false".
```

Comment: Ask your IIS administrator to configure that for you, as the message said.

Comment: @LexLi is there nothing I can do then?

Comment: Yes, you as a developer has nothing to do (nor any right to do).

Comment: @LexLi ok thank you :)